# How safe is an email BCC field?

Tags: privacy, email

If I want to send an email to multiple recipients without them knowing each other, can I consider the BCC field safe enough to do this?

Obviously the server will still know and have a log of who the recipients are, but if we assume that server will not be hacked would the BCC field be enough?

Comment: Seeing as your question was "without THEM knowing each other" , I would say yes, it would be enough.

Comment: The catch is that, and it happens, when a bcc member replies to all.

Comment: @George Doesn't that just reply to the sender, and all "known" receivers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea of the BCC field is indeed to keep recipients undisclosed from each other. But it should not be understood as a reliable security feature and I wouldn't trust it in a life-and-death situation.

Servers often add additional headers to emails during processing. These headers might, as a side effect, inadvertently reveal BCC recipients to everyone else. For example, this has been a problem with various email encryption implementations. Some research on that can be found in the paper [Correcting Privacy Violations in Blind-Carbon-Copy (BCC) Encrypted Email](https://crypto.stanford.edu/portia/papers/bb-bcc.pdf). From the abstract:

> We show that many widely deployed email encryption systems reveal the
>   identities of Blind- Carbon-Copy (BCC) recipients. For example,
>   encrypted email sent using Microsoft Outlook completely exposes the
>   identity of every BCC recipient. Additionally, several
>   implementations of PGP expose the full name and email address of BCC
>   recipients.

I could imagine that similar problems exist with anti-spam filters or other forms of email processing that your mail server might employ.

Also, there have been flawed implementations in the past. For example, [Microsoft Outlook Express Information Disclosure Vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/viewAlert.x?alertId=8063)
(CVE-2004-2137):

> Microsoft Outlook Express 6.0 SP1 and prior contain a vulnerability that could cause private information to be disclosed to e-mail recipients.  The application may arbitrarily allow a recipient to view the addresses listed in the BCC: field.

As an alternative I'd suggest you to send the mail to each BCC recipient individually. If there are many of them, you can use a bulk email plugin for your mail client that will send the mails one by one.

*You can find a related answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/143246/95381).*